# Ubuntu 21.10 not shutting down properly

Tags: suspend, shutdown

How can I work out why my laptop has stopped shutting down properly?  If you select "power off" everything appears to shut down, but the fan keeps spinning, and never ends unless you long hold down the power button or unplug the charger and let the power run out.

If you flip the screen down to suspend, it also goes blank and completely unresponsive.  This behaviour has been happening for about two weeks.

Other than that, when it's on, there's no other sign of trouble.  I've run `apt dist-upgrade` regularly since installing 21.10.

The system specs are:

```
$ uname -a
Linux *** 5.13.0-22-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 13:21:36 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          2
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      21
Model:                           112
Model name:                      AMD A9-9410 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G
Stepping:                        0
Frequency boost:                 enabled
CPU MHz:                         1419.579
CPU max MHz:                     2900.0000
CPU min MHz:                     1400.0000
BogoMIPS:                        5789.45
Virtualisation:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       64 KiB
L1i cache:                       128 KiB
L2 cache:                        2 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0,1
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full AMD retpoline, IBPB conditional, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxex
                                 t fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good acc_power nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmul
                                 qdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy ab
                                 m sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext p
                                 tsc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate ssbd ibpb vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc
                                 _scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov

$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] (rev c1)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15b3
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Platform Security Processor
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Audio Dummy Host Bridge
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 4b)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4b)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney HT Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney Address Maps
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney DRAM Configuration
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney Miscellaneous Configuration
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney PM Configuration
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney NB Performance Monitor
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Comment: I suggest you look for errors in the logs. `journalctl -b -1 -p3` will show errors for the last boot. If that shows nothing remove the -p3 and examine the end of the output where presumably things are going wrong. Add anything relevant to your question

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue, it's extremely annoying! However I found (after days of research) a solution that may not solve the "wakeup after suspend" problem, but now my system is shutting down and restarting as it should.
Even though I can't find the original post, the site I found it from was [stephenwagner.com](https://www.stephenwagner.com).
Here is what they suggested and it worked out fine for the "shutdown issue":
Open Terminal and open the GRUB file

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

type your password and Enter (no characters appear here)

It is now in editing mode of your Grub configuration file. Be careful! Any wrong changes may destroy your system startup options!

Find the line that says:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it by adding nomodeset

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

After that press `Ctrl+o` ("write out") and then `Ctrl+x` ("exit")

Then, to save changes, update the Grub File in terminal using

```
sudo update-grub
```

Once done, reboot your machine. It should be working now. If not, please let me know!

Comment: Please don't recommend `nomodeset` willy nilly. It has a very specific and narrow usage as troubleshooting/workaround parameter. It is NOT to be used permanently as it prevents the usage of any graphics drivers, as already commented in another copy/paste answer you gave.

Comment: Hmm, thank you Vatarian for the suggestion and ChanganAuto for the warning.  It does indeed seem to "fix" the issue, I will do some more digging about nomodeset.

Comment: Bug in kernel 5.13 and AMD APUs https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.13/+bug/1958519